# is there a R function to group data when they have less than X% of difference on their X, Y and Z values?

Tags: r, grouping, percentage, xyz

Good evening to you all,

I'm trying to group data according to their values on 3 columns together. I would like to group rows that have X, Y and Z coordinates that are less than 12% different from each other.
In other words, for each observation, I would like to check whether their X, Y and Z values are less than 12% different from another observation in the table.
My data frame looks more or less like this:

| ID | X | Y | Z |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 3 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 27 | 42 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 32 | 3 | 58 |  |
| 4 | 33 | 3 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 25 | 2 | 22 |  |
| 6 | 37 | 119 | 3 |  |

IDs 1 and 4 should be part of the same group as there is less than 12% of difference between their X, Y and Z coordinates.
I was thinking of looping through the whole dataframe (looping through x to find similar rows, then through Y to find similar rows and finally through Z and then check if some results would appear through X, Y and Z, but it is awfully complicated and seems to not be working very well.
I tried as well to group them by hand in such a way:

```r
df %>% group_by(IDscrit) %>% summarize(n())
df$group <- ifelse(df$X <2 & df$Y <2 & df$Z <2, "group1", 
       ifelse(df$X <5 & df$X >2 & df$Y <5 &df$Y >2 & df$Z <5 & df$Z >2, "group2", NA))
```

But for very obvious reasons (not handy and I am excluding a lot of values of being grouped arbitrarily although they could be close to each other, like the for example if my table was displaying these values:

| ID | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 26 | 6 | 3 | 2 |

they would not be grouped, although they should), therefore this cannot work either...
I would be super grateful for any advice, really any... It is way above my abilities in coding and I don't even know by which part I should pick this problem anymore.

Comment: Please format your post to show the ddata

Comment: What do you do when a is 10% different from b, and b is 10% different from c, but a is >10% different from c? What group does b go into?

Comment: Also it's not clear what you mean by 10% different. In two points `a` and `b`, all of x, y, and z are each < 10% different? < 10% different on average? The distance between them is <10% of the length? And 10% of what? 10% of `a` or 10% of `b`?

Comment: Are you meaning Euclidean distance between observations?

Comment: I'd assume two groups, one for a and b and one for b and c; and The other qualitative and quantitative columns in the data frame would help me decide on which one would be the best.
Also, each time, the data would be calculated from the data in the cell under examination. So 10% of X, 10% of Y, 10% of Z.

Comment: @PaulSmith I'm ashamed to say that I'm not entirely sure I know **exactly** what a Euclidean distance is. It sounds very much like it but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The following gives

max {abs(X_a - X_b), abs(Y_a - Y_b), abs(Z_a - Z_b)}

```
df <- tribble(
~ID, ~X, ~Y, ~Z,    
1, 33, 3, 1, 
2, 27, 42, 1, 
3, 32, 3, 58, 
4, 33, 3, 1, 
5, 25, 2, 22, 
6, 37, 119, 3)

dist(df[,-1],method = "maximum")
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
2  39                
3  57  57            
4   0  39  57        
5  21  40  36  21    
6 116  77 116 116 117
```

Now, you can form the groups you want, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Using `DF` defined reproducibly int he Note at the end we define `is.near` which takes two numeric vectors each representing X, Y and Z and returns TRUE if they are within 12% of each other and FALSE otherwise. (Change `is.near` as needed if you need a different definition of nearness.) Using that we form an adjacency matrix A from the rows, convert that to a graph g and extract the id's of the connected components.

```
library(igraph)

is.near <- function(r, s) {
  max(abs(r - s)) < 0.12 * min(abs(r), abs(s))
}

nr <- nrow(DF)
s <- split(as.matrix(DF[-1]), 1:nr)
A <- outer(s, s, Vectorize(is.near)) - diag(nr)
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(A, "undirected")
transform(DF, group = components(g)$membership)
##   ID  X   Y  Z group
## 1  1 33   3  1     1
## 2  2 27  42  1     2
## 3  3 32   3 58     3
## 4  4 33   3  1     1
## 5  5 25   2 22     4
## 6  6 37 119  3     5

plot(g)
```

[image: screenshot]

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, X = c(33L, 27L, 32L, 33L, 25L, 37L), 
    Y = c(3L, 42L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 119L), Z = c(1L, 1L, 58L, 1L, 
    22L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Oh yes indeed it seems to be exactly what I'm looking for but the code doesn't do the same thing for me and to be honest I don't quite understand it.
I'm indeed particularly interested in the creation of the "group" column in the dataframe.